# Dwarves not dumping Refuse from former Refuse stockpile

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am digging a moat around my fort, so i designated a new refuse stockpile so i can dig the moat, and removed the old one, but now, the refuse is staying where it is, i tried dumping it to a dump zone, but it does nothing(I made sure that the items were designated to be dumped)

Comment: Are the items marked as forbidden? My knowledge is a bit out of date, but dumped items at least used to be marked forbidden after dumping, and forbidden items wouldn't get dumped.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to add more details to your question. Like: what are the haulers doing instead of hauling? What other tasks are competing with hauling and having higher priority? How are your standing orders on dumping?